# VisualForce Page - Printing Opportunity name from new Quote page

Tags: apex, visualforce, canvas

I want to display the an Opportunity Name from inside the new "Quote" page.
this is how my page looks like:

```
<apex:page showHeader="true" standardController="Opportunity">
<h1>name : {!Opportunity.name}</h1>
<br/>
<h1> org: {!$Organization.Name} </h1> 
</apex:page>
```

The global {$Organization.Name} bounded variable does show
but the  {!Opportunity.name} prints nothing.

This sounds really basic, what am I missing here?

Thanks!

Comment: check whether you are correctly passing the opportunity id in the url?

Comment: the opportunity Id should be passed like this `https://baseurl/apex/pageName?id=opportunityId`

Comment: why are you using the Opportunity standard Controller instead of the Quote standard Controller

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use the standard controller to reference a specific record, it needs to know the record identifier, or ID, of the record to work with. It uses the ID to retrieve the data, and to save it back to the database when the record’s data is changed.

To Ge a record id create a Opportunity and when the Opportunity details page finishes loading, look at the URL for the page.

The URL will look something like this:

https://SalesforceInstance/006D000000JRBes

Here **006D000000JRBes** is record id. Select the record ID, and copy it to your clipboard. Now go to your visual force page and pass this copied record id

https://SalesforceInstance/apex/YOUR_PAGE_NAME?id=**RECORD_ID**

Press Return to load the page at the new URL